# Google limitation about Daily Content Generation

Tags: seo, google-search

if i add 1.000 new uniq content to my blog everyday and send them to google sitemap scanner, What google say to this situation ? i do not want to blocked by google.

Note: My content value can change up to 10.000 content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I think Stackoverflow should implement a feature suggesting people to migrate their questions to Webmaster Pro when they are tagged with SEO, rather than voting for closing. It is a tedious process...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's policy, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not care about the amount of content you add to your blog. It cares about its quality and relevancy. You would only be penalized because of low quality content, not the amount.

That being said, Google's crawlers may not want to crawl all your content right way (it is not a capacity issue). If your blog is new, they prefer to take a bit of content and check whether it ranks. Later, they may decide to crawl and index more of it.

Crawlers will also adapt to your server's capacity when crawling.